# how to include a spring project into another spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am new to spring and currently struggling in understanding the settings required for using an existing spring project in my current project

I have a spring project which has all the service for communicating with the database and webservice.

I am writing a new application which neeeds to talk to the database and webservice.

I thought of re-using the existing implementation in the other project.

I included the project in the build path of the current project.

However I am getting dependency injection error. 
Now I am kind of stuck to see what all the other files I need to have in my current project settings so that I can re-use the existing project.

Should I need to import the context file of the other project in to my current one? If so can someone point me to the documentation where I can refer for some guidance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give it a shot. Hope I can bring about clarity to your question... =D

When you say "I included the project in the build path of the current project.", I assumed you added a spring web project as a dependency to another spring web project. In summary, you can't add a spring web project as a dependency of another spring web project. Let's take some time to understand how you wire a bean to do injection in spring container first...

When you use spring framework, you will find a similar code in your web.xml like the following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What you have just done is to use spring framework's servlet to handle every request URL that ends with .htm. Of course you may configure it otherwise.

You should also have another xml that contains all your bean tags. By default, it is spring-servlet.xml. In this spring-servlet.xml, you specify which bean shall be injected to which bean if you are going the xml configuration approach. If you are using annotation approach, you should have a  tag to scan all your existing @Component (and its derived annotations) annotated classes, then use @Inject or @Autowired annotation to inject the declared instance(bean). For example:

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="org.companyname.webappname" />
<context:annotation-config />
```

So far, what I have been explaining is how to declare a bean in a spring container. An "injection" happens only when you declare a bean (to live in spring container when web server starts) in a spring container, and specify which class it should be injected into.

So now that you have two spring web projects (assumption), with two web.xml and two spring container, you will have a problem getting the base-project's spring container to find the dependent spring web project's packages/classes. I suggest you move all the classes in the dependent project into the base-project and only have one spring container (one web.xml).

Another way is to create a Java Library Project, place all your services, DAO and web services classes in it and build it as jar. In your base project, add the jar file (as dependencies) and either do a component-scan on the jar's package or declare it in xml with the jar's package. Either way, you should only have one spring container, one web.xml.

Hope I am not confusing you.

You got to understand how the IoC container work first. Here is where you need to read and digest how spring IoC works: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html

Update: if you are doing a non web spring project, the concept of having only one spring container still stands. The solution of moving dependent project's classes to a jar file is still valid. Except that you don't configure spring via web.xml. =D

Comment: Hey, check this out: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077837/java-se/hello--osgi--part-1--bundles-for-beginners.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the file containing the bean definitions of the service layer(say, service-context.xml) into the new project.
It can be done as:

```
    <import  resource="classpath:service-context.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have setup the project.
In general you would need to use

An example of this can be seen [here](https://github.com/serkan-ozal/spring-jdbc-roma) (see the directions on how to include the project in your own application)